# How does the wavefront of sound or any other type of longitudinal waves look like?

Tags: waves

In reality there is no crest on a longitudinal wave, even though compression is basically crest. So on this basis, there is really no visible wavefront. Is this true?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23605/what-do-bullet-trails-really-look-like

Comment: @dmckee, so does longitudinal wave have wavefronts (not in the case of a bullet, because the boundary is visible because there isn't enough time for air to expand)? I mean just under normal conditional. Is it just a line connecting all points of compressions or rarefactions?

Comment: I don't follow what you mean when you write "wavefront". All waves have them in the conventional meaning---the continuous loci of maximum or minimum disturbance---but I suspect that you have something particular in mind. Mind you having such a locus doesn't mean that it is visible to the unaided eye the displacements of surface waves in water are.

Comment: By the definition that wavefront is a locus of all points in phase, then any wave can have wavefront?